# When appending a python variable to a list I am getting object values

Tags: python

```
print("Device discovered: %s" % remote)
m.append(remote)
print(m)
```

I am getting the following result. How Can I get same value is the list names m

```
Device discovered: 0013A20041481642 - REMOTE
[<digi.xbee.devices.RemoteZigBeeDevice object at 0x7f42c312ceb8>]
```

Comment: You have to convert it to a string literal before you print it.

Comment: Not sure what you expected or what you think is unexpected.  Is the problem that you are surprised by the difference between `0013A20041481642` (a number used by the `RemoteZigBeeDevice` for whatever zigbee-specific purpose) and `0x7f42c312ceb8` (an ID assigned by the Python interpreter itself to the `RemoteZigBeeDevice` instance, just like it will assign an ID to any object...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `m.append(str(remote))`? It is possible there is a `__str__` function implemented in `remote` object. Such magic function will handle object to string conversion when it's necessary. When you format the object it is necessary to convert to str but when you append it to a list it's not.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks It works .Y copy.copy() is not work with this model

Comment: Hit the enter too quick, edited. Martijn has a better answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

List contents use the `repr()` result of the objects contained, which in turn uses the `__repr__` method on an object.

`print()` converts objects with `str()`, which will use a `__str__` method, if present, `__repr__` otherwise.

You `remote` object (a `digi.xbee.devices.RemoteZigBeeDevice` instance) only has a `__str__` method, and no `__repr__` method. Implement the latter to customise how your object is shown in a list.

Alternatively, print all individual values in the list with:

```
print(*m)
```

These are then space separated, use `sep='...'` to specify a different separator.

Or you could convert all the objects in the list to a string before printing:

```
print([str(obj) for obj in m])
```

and print the list of strings.